# How to click last child link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to click on the last anchor element of the class

> Class name "g1-pagination pagelinks" Anchor Element "Next >"

here is my HTML

```
<div class="Next-buttons">
 <nav class="g1-pagination pagelinks">
  <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="http://buzztache.com/with-you/"><span>&lt; BACK</span></a>
   </li> 
   <li>
     <a href="http://buzztache.com/with-you/3/"><span>NEXT &gt;</span></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

here what I have tried so fare.

```
var nextlink = document.getElementsByClassName('g1-pagination pagelinks');
nextlink[0].lastElementChild.click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
$('.Next-buttons').find('li:last a:first')[0].click();
```

Info: https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Another way to do it ( bad way );

```
var link =  $('.Next-buttons').find('li:last a:first').attr('href');
window.location = link
```

Or pure js as ( Credits: [@itsgoingdown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2913508/itsgoingdown) );

```
nextlink[0].lastElementChild.getElementsByTagName('A')[0].click();
```

Comment: Yup! the result is the href of element.

Comment: Or `nextlink[0].lastElementChild.getElementsByTagName('A')[0].click();` if you want to stick with vanilla js

Comment: Sorry. Just use "click" method to click it. I wrote "attr('href')" in a case you can write a click or something :D sorry...

Comment: No click is performed.

Comment: What is console saying ? :|

Comment: Returns the whole anchor tag.

Comment: I don't know why, it should work. Try updated answer

Comment: The jQuery `click()` function runs event listeners, but it doesn't perform the default click action of following the link.

Comment: I am using this jQuery('.Next-buttons').find('li:last a:first').click() cause the website is wordpress based and dont support $

Comment: I think problem is the "span". You can use the second code or pure javascript as @Barmar said.

Comment: Oh! Alright buddy. so he should write it as answer.

Comment: @Lost_In_Library you got the right selector for jquery, but as said before, you need to convert that `jquery` element into `dom`, so it would be `$('.Next-buttons').find('li:last a:first')[0].click();`

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed that. You deserved the answer points mate :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you've selected an answer (and a very complete one at that) but I don't think you'll need to use `.find()`, you should be able to just target in one shot.

```
$('.Next-buttons li:last a:first')[0].click();
```

Also, just for some who might try, `.trigger('click')` doesn't work on anchor tags unless you've added a specific event to them. You'll always need to use `[0].click()` instead.